# How to apply “Table Style Medium 4” template formatting to excel created using open xml?

Tags: excel, formatting, openxml, view-styles

Hi I have a few datatables (No DataSet). I have created a method which will write datatable to excel. after writing data from datatable to excel, I will again call the same method of excel generation and pass the datatable which will create excel worksheet and apped it to existing. For each datatable a worksheet will get created.

I am using the following way to create excel worksheet. [[Click Here]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811143/export-datatable-to-excel-with-open-xml-sdk-in-c-sharp?answertab=active#tab-top)

I want to apply formatting to it. Built in style "Table Style Medium 4". How is it possible in shortest and easiest way?

PS: Dont want to apply by each cell individually. want to apply to complete sheet.